# How to add bootstrap class for input field time and date in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

This my date field and time field.

```
{!! Form::input('date', 'eventDate', $value = null, $options = array()) !!}
{!! Form::input('time', 'time', $value = null, $options = array()) !!}
```

Where should I insert ['class' => 'form-control'] bootstrap class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

You can add it with $options array.

```
{!! Form::input('time', 'time', $value = null, $options = array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::input('time', 'time', $value = null, $options = array('class'=>'form-control')) !!}
```